# How to collect all event types in Firebase analytics?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-analytics

I am trying to do catch every event types in a single function instead of creating a function to collect them all up using Google Cloud/Firebase Functions.
Normally we can say

```
exports.eventLog = functions.analytics.event('screen_view').onLog((event) =>
```

However, I don't want to create functions for every event type like screen_view and so on. 
I have tried

```
exports.eventLog = functions.analytics.event('*').onLog((event) =>
```

But since Google does this by HTTP Post, it is not possible.

Is there a simple way to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *firebaser here* I looked into the code and docs, and from what I see there this is currently not possible. But I'm checking with some of the product experts, so hang in there.

Comment: Note that even if this is possible, it would still only trigger for conversion events. If you want to analyze *all* analytics events, it's better to stream all the data into BigQuery and analyze it there.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen Thanks a lot for your time and input. I am trying to do analyse the events and crashes in mobile apps using Firebase. Not sure if I should use BigQuery, but as you've said, it seems like the only way.